# Worked on 2 hours but cannot clicked on the button with Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to click on this button but my codes do not work.

The last one I tried is this: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app/main/app/div/div/e-arsiv/taslaklar/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/uc-quick-filter[@type='3M]").click()`

and I get this error:

```
elenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression /html/body/app/main/app/div/div/e-arsiv/taslaklar/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/uc-quick-filter[@type='3M] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '/html/body/app/main/app/div/div/e-arsiv/taslaklar/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/uc-quick-filter[@type='3M]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

here is the [html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGNLY.png)

Answer (score 1):

you have a missing enclosing single quote on your `text`.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app/main/app/div/div/e-arsiv/taslaklar/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/uc-quick-filter[@type='3M']").click()
```

Comment: unfortunately it gives the error below. I also tried using an implicit wait : selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <uc-quick-filter _ngcontent-c8="" titleshort="3A" type="3M" _nghost-c10="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">...</uc-quick-filter> is not clickable at point (319, 147). Other element would receive the click: <div id="serviceLoading" style="display: block;">...</div>

Comment: try this `driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app/main/app/div/div/e-arsiv/taslaklar/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/uc-quick-filter[@type='3M'][1]").click()`

Comment: same error :( <div id="serviceLoading" style="display: block;">...</div> is apparently blocking us to click on the button. However, I don't see anything on the screen that blocks.

Comment: execute_script method solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Absolute xpath is less preferable. Use css like this

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector ("uc-quick-filter.ng-untouched.ng-invalid[type='3M']").click()
```

Comment: this didn't worked neither :( throwing --> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"uc-quick-filter.ng-untouched.ng-invalid[type='3M']"}

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy again the xpath using chrome--> F12 -->right click on element -->copy -->xpath